# How to view log in Spark in HDInsight after app exit?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

When the application is running, I am able to view the log from the RM UI. But after the application exits, I got this message when trying to view the log:

> Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server.
>   Log Server url may not be configured  java.lang.Exception: Unknown
>   container. Container either has not started or has already completed
>   or doesn't belong to this node at all.

I looked around my HDInsight storage but I could not find any log file.

Comment: How is your cluster deployed? What is the url you are using?

Comment: I don't know how the cluster is deployed, because it is managed by HDInsight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using *YARN* for your *Spark* execution, you could use its built-in log system.

According to the official *Spark* [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html):

> If log aggregation is turned on (with the yarn.log-aggregation-enable config), container logs are copied to HDFS and deleted on the local machine. These logs can be viewed from anywhere on the cluster with the “yarn logs” command.

*HDInsight* clusters support this type of logging. In order to access them, the command below can be used from a command line:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <app ID>
```

To identify the application ID, you might want to access the *Hadoop* user interface and look up for the *All Applications* section:

[image: Hadoop user interface]

**Note**: In order to output the entire log into a file, you might want to append `> TextFile.txt` to the above command.